# Updating view background color with animation makes app unresponsive

Tags: ios, multithreading, user-interface, uiviewanimation

I encountered the problem, can't find a good solution so far.

After some certain actions I want to change the background color of my self.view with animation. So I do something like this:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor;
        }];
```

And I want this animation to be slow and easy, that's why it can be likfe 3-5 seconds, not just a quick switch form one to another.

The problem is that if I make it on the Main thread it makes my app completely unresponsive for these 3-5 seconds while the animation is performing. If I make it on the background thread I have a lot of problem, which is expected.

Is there any good solution how to slowly update background color with animation without freezing the screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` option instead of `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut` to allow user interaction.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor;
}];
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be "instead of", you can "or" the two options together.

Comment: @rdelmar - Yeah, that's what I did. Thanks anyway